# How to put a formula into a table cell

Tags: tables, equations

I need to insert into a table cell a formula that requires the summation sign and I apparently do something wrong and the compiler just throws me back errors and I really don't know how to solve this.

```
\begin{tabular}{ c || c c c }
\hline 
Linea & Costo & Esecuzioni & Totale \\ \hline                        
1 & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ \\
2 & $n+1$ & $2$ & $2(n+1)$ \\
3 & \begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}\nolimits' C_n \end{equation} & $2$ & $2(n+1)$ \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` inside a table cell. If you want it to look like a displayed equation, you can do this:

```
3 & \(\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}\nolimits' C_n \) & $2$ & $2(n+1)$ \\
```

Here, `\( ... \)` is inline math (more-or-less equivalent to `$ ... $`), and `\displaystyle` is self-explanatory: it typesets the equation in the style as it was a displayed math.

Comment: What if you want the equation numbering?

Comment: If you want a numbered equatiob insid a table, you do something wrong.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please, tell me what's wrong with the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

You *can* actually put `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` in a `tabular` cell, but you need to box it up first, either using a `vbox`, `minipage`, `parbox`, or something similar.

Whether or not that's a good idea is another issue; if your `tabular` is floating then it's almost certainly a *bad* idea (as the numbering might get messed up)

```
3 & \vbox{\begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}\nolimits' C_n \end{equation}} & $2$ & $2(n+1)$ \\
4 & \parbox{3cm}{\begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}\nolimits' C_n \end{equation}} & $2$ & $2(n+1)$ \\
5 & \begin{minipage}{4cm}\begin{equation} \sum_{n=1}\nolimits' C_n \end{equation}\end{minipage} & $2$ & $2(n+1)$ \
```

Comment: how do I know if my tabular is floating? (sorry for this basic question, but I'm a rookie and I'm learning by doing...)

Comment: @haunted85 if it's in a `table` environment. have a look at the not so short guide to latex

Comment: But how do I know what size to give it? I am not specifying a fixed size in `\begin{tabular}`.