# Is there a simple way to create a latex equivalent of this (ms)word table template?

Tags: tables

I'd like to know if there's a newbie friendly way to create something like the table (it doesn't have to be a table if there's some other options that produce a similar template) in the pictures. In word it was pretty easy to do. Now I'd like to do the same in latex if possible.

I tried to create a table but couldn't enter equations into the cells. From searching online I found this question ([How to put a formula into a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76189/how-to-put-a-formula-into-a-table-cell)) and one answer says that we can't use $\begin{equation} .. \end{equation}$ inside table cells. The second answer says it is possible but not a good idea if the tabular is a floating

My question: is there a way to create this "template" once (in latex) and then treat the bigger cell like it's the whole page? Ignore what's outside of it's borders so I can use the same "template" for multiple pages.

I started with this code example. The 'summary' cell looks nice horizontally but it should be the only cell in it's row with other rows with columns over/under it.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}


With width specified:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
        \hline
        Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
        Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
        However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
        Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
        across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
        but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
        Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
        Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
        throughout the evening. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This looks pretty hacky to me. It'd be nice to know if there's a proper way of doing this.

Note that I'm new to linux and latex. Using Texstudio on openSUSE.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your  paper size, with a left margin of 20 cm?

Comment: It's a standard A4. Portrait layout.

Comment: You can't have a left margin of 20cm, a right margin of 5cm, and text in paper width of 21 cm!

Comment: @Bernard: A left margin of `20cm`? ;-)

Comment: XD. No. I can't. I should have put 20 mm there. Sorry. I'll edit the embarrasiing picture.

Comment: And the right margin is 5 mm?

Comment: Yes. All others are 5 mm except the left which is 20.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: That's for Baron Münchhausen…

Comment: I can't exactly see the link between the image you posted and the code. Must there be a header and a footer as in the image? Where must your table go? What do you mean exactly with ‘specifed width’?

Comment: @Bernard No there's no need for headers or footers. The dots at the footer are from word online's page-end marks or something. Well with the code I wanted to create something that looked similar to the template in the picture but like I said it seemed too hacky to me. The table (it doesn't have to be a table if there's another way) needs to go into (fill ) a A4 sheet. With the specified margins.

Comment: I was mentioning the upper part with ‘TITLE’, &c;, and the lower part with ‘Date’  and the like, and the frames.

Comment: Yes. Those cells in the upper/lower part are mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, "simple" is relarive I guess. Here's a concept of what you can do with the help of the *tikzpagenodes* package and the *calc* library of *TikZ*. First you specify the margins, the text separation and the height of the boxes as you like. Then a picture is drawn in `overlay` mode to get the various black lines. The synatx for the coordinate computation is

- `($(A)+(B)$)`: add the coordinates `A` and `B`
- `($(A)!c!(B)$)`: the point at fraction 'c' between `A` and `B`

For the header I already defined somthing that looks a bit like your requirement, try playing with the numbers to tweak it. For the footer you'll have to define a few more coordinates.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% ===== set these values to your liking

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\LeftMargin}{20mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\RightMargin}{5mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\TopMargin}{25mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\BottomMargin}{15mm}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Sep}{2mm} % distance between black border and text

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\TopBoxHeight}{15mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\BottomBoxHeight}{20mm}

% ============================================

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\LEFT}{\LeftMargin + \Sep}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\RIGHT}{\RightMargin + \Sep}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\TOP}{\TopMargin + \Sep + \TopBoxHeight}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\BOTTOM}{\BottomMargin + \Sep + \BottomBoxHeight}


\usepackage%
[   left=\LEFT,
    right=\RIGHT,
    top=\TOP,
    bottom=\BOTTOM
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \coordinate (A) at ($(current page text area.north west)+(-\Sep,+\Sep)$);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(current page text area.north east)+(+\Sep,+\Sep)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(current page text area.south west)+(-\Sep,-\Sep)$);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(current page text area.south east)+(+\Sep,-\Sep)$);

    \draw (C) rectangle (B); % box around text

    \path (A) ++ (0,\TopBoxHeight) coordinate (E);
    \path (B) ++ (0,\TopBoxHeight) coordinate (F);

    \draw (A) rectangle (F); % top box

    \path (C) ++ (0,-\BottomBoxHeight) coordinate (G);
    \path (D) ++ (0,-\BottomBoxHeight) coordinate (H);

    \draw (G) rectangle (D); % bottom box

    % ===== add whatever you like here

    \coordinate (I) at ($(A)!0.375!(B)$);
    \coordinate (J) at ($(A)!0.75!(B)$);

    \coordinate (K) at ($(I)+(0,\TopBoxHeight/2)$);
    \coordinate (L) at ($(J)+(0,\TopBoxHeight/2)$);
    \coordinate (M) at ($(B)+(0,\TopBoxHeight/2)$);

    \draw (I) -- ++ (0,\TopBoxHeight) coordinate (N);
    \draw (J) -- ++ (0,\TopBoxHeight) coordinate (O);
    \draw (K) -- (M);

    \node[text width=5cm, align=center] at ($(E)!0.5!(I)$) {\textsc{Xitragupten}\\ some more text};
    \node[text width=5cm, align=center] at ($(K)!0.5!(O)$) {debt register};
    \node[text width=5cm, align=center] at ($(I)!0.5!(L)$) {the beyond};
    \node[text width=5cm, align=center] at ($(M)!0.5!(O)$) {134217728};
    \node[text width=5cm, align=center] at ($(J)!0.5!(M)$) {131072};

    % ===== a helper to show the positions of the coordinates   

    \coordinate (center) at ($(A)!0.5!(D)$);
    \foreach \P in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O}
    {   \node[fill= yellow!30, draw, inner sep=1pt,circle] (dummy) at ($(\P)!0.3!(center)$) {\P};
        \draw[-latex] (dummy) -- (\P);
    }

    \foreach \x [count=\c] in {hoffset, voffset, oddsidemargin, topmargin, headheight, headsep, textheight, textwidth, marginparsep, marginparwidth, footskip, paperwidth, paperheight}
    {   \node[right] at (0,-0.7*\c) {\x\ = \pgfmathparse{\csname\x\endcsname}\pgfmathresult pt = \pgfmathparse{\csname\x\endcsname/28.452756}\pgfmathresult cm};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Well, with simple I meant something that could be done by a latex newbie definitely with less code than what you've written. But you've done almost all the work for me. So, now I believe I can tweak your code a little bit and get exactly what I was aiming for. This is a great answer and helps me a lot. I hope it will, also, be useful for others.Thank You very much. :)